# <spring:bind command object not being populated

Tags: spring-mvc

In my application, one of the jsp is successfully able to pass input parameters through command object to my controller. However I took the same approach for another jsp and its controller, it does not work. I never worked for any other JSPs.

**Following is the code - spring xml**

```
    <bean id="uploadController"
        class="com.UploadController">
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>formBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>
                com..TemplateDownloadFormBean
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>uploadTemplates</value>
        </property>
        <property name="successView">
            <value>uploadSuccess</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
public class UploadController extends SimpleFormController {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3208409086358916855L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(UploadController.class);

    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
            throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Entered UploadController - OnSubmit");

        TemplateDownloadFormBean formBean = (TemplateDownloadFormBean) command;
        logger.debug(formBean.getSearchString());
        Enumeration en = request.getAttributeNames();

        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            logger.debug(en.nextElement());
        }

        return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
    }
```

**JSP**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<form action="uploadTemplates.do" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><spring:hasBindErrors name="formBean">
            <c:forEach var="errMsgObj" items="${errors.allErrors}">
                <div align="center" class="errorStyle"><spring:message
                    code="${errMsgObj.code}" /></div>
            </c:forEach>
        </spring:hasBindErrors></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <spring:bind path="formBean.searchString">
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="searchString" /></td>
        </spring:bind>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="SearchTemplate"
            name="SearchTemplate" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This same declaration structure works well for my other JSP in the same application. But fails here. Please if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: logger.debug(formBean.getSearchString()); has null for searchstring.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring `form` tags as they are capable of rendering the correct `<input>` element names. Your error is probably here (note the different name):

```
<input type="text" name="formBean.searchString" />
```

Tag `<spring:bind>` is in your case absolutely useless. That tag has a different purpose, unrelated to your usecase.

---

Btw. are you aware that you are using some pretty old stuff in Spring :)? Nowdays the handlers are done via `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations. If you are new to Spring, go check Spring documentation and the [Greenhouse reference project](https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse).

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I will try your suggestion in a min and see if it helps. When I first started the application a month ago or so, I took the latest spring jar and started working around it. But hit exactly same issue probably the spring:bind could be the culprit, but I thought lets go back to older version. I picked spring jar from an app I worked on ages ago.. and this is it. Now to redo the application using  spring 3 again, I think I am running short of time. So will get this working somehow.

Comment: I upgraded my application to spring 3 and redid the ongoing part with annotations. Its working well. Thanks.